# Knocking in a cricket bat

Tags: time, sports

The conventional way of knocking in a new cricket bat is with a mallet but it can take up to 5 hours.

Are there any innovative original alternative easier, less tiring and time consuming options ?

Answer (score 2):

It’s been a long time since I’ve played cricket and even longer since I bought a new bat.

But the last bat I bought they had a rolling machine to do it for you. Took less than 15mins.

Alternatively, I used to hang an old ball in a sock, hang it from a tree and then hit it. Much slower process but as a kid it was good fun.

Answer (score 0):

I found no way of making this process quicker. You can ship your any and pay for someone to do it for you though. It costs around £20 ($25.47).

There is a service available [here.](https://www.talentcricket.co.uk/knocking_in_service/knocking_in_service/c31p772.html)
I am not affiliated with the service.